# How to display all functions (hooks, filters, or custom php) used on a page inline

Tags: plugins

I would like to display a page and all the hooks, classes, or php custom function inline with page content without var_dump.

The purpose of this would be to audit a seven year old site that has 18k pages and many developers coding and writing functions over the years (without documentation) to discern which functions are being used on which pages and if there are functions that are not being used on the site at all, deprecate them.

Thank you!

Comment: @jacobpeattie, reworded question to conform to rules. please remove on hold.

Comment: @jackjohansson, reworded question to conform to rules. please remove on hold.

Comment: Are you looking to enumerate _all_ of the hooks, classes and PHP functions used, or just the ones that are used on a particular _page_? If it's on a page, are you asking about the post type `page` or on a particular... template, core page (like archive or post), admin page, or... otherwise?

Comment: @StephanSamuel, Yes I am looking to enumerate all of the hooks, classes and php functions that used on each front-end page (post, page, cpt, etc), excluding admin. The functions should display inline with the content, not just a list. Thank you

Comment: There are options in PHP, see this [so] thread: »[Print PHP Call Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1423157/2505105)«.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for more than one thing:

- **Enumerate hooks:** this can be found in the `$wp_filter` global variable. If you're looking for just the names of the hooks, use `array_keys()`. For some code examples, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224209/wordpress-how-do-i-get-all-the-registered-functions-for-the-content-filter) or there are plenty of other examples.
- **Enumerate classes:** use the PHP function `get_declared_classes()`.
- **Enumerate functions:** similarly, use the PHP function `get_defined_functions()`. This should give you an associative array-of-arrays and it sounds like you probably just want the ones under the `user` key.
- **Filter these lists:** this is the tricker part. Probably you'd need to build a reference list of things you want to filter *out,* like all the WP custom functions (a long list). All of the above-referenced sources give you arrays, so `array_filter()` is probably your best friend here.
- **Display your content:** probably you will end up with one or more arrays containing the content that you want to display. Build your `foreach` loops to dump the contents on the screen where and how you'd like. I'm not exactly sure what, "inline with page content," means but a few quick runs should help you sort things out and make it look as you prefer. Keep in mind that if you have an array of strings to dump to the screen in a delimited list, `implode(', ', $array_of_strings)` gives good results.

If you're looking for *what gets called* on a particular page as opposed to what's been defined, the classes and functions are hard without breaking into the PHP parser (or re-parsing the PHP file that was called). Hooks are relatively easy in this case, just use the `all` filter. This will give you what's being called, from end to end, in the rendering of the page.

If you're looking for *what's defined in a PHP file,* that's just an exercise in parsing or hooking into the PHP parser. Your bigger problem here is that a particular page load in WP has a very loose correlation to the number of PHP files that are loaded. There is no one-to-one correlation between the URL visited and a single PHP file loaded. For example, each of the support classes, like `WP_Post` and `wpdb`, are defined in a single PHP file, none of which may be responsible directly for any output to any page load, but all of which are essential to just about every page load.

Without more information on exactly what you're trying to accomplish (specifically, why), it's hard to say more. So... what are you trying to accomplish? Is this enough background information to help you accomplish your task?

Comment: I think I will start here and then update this thread as I go along. The purpose of this would be to audit a seven year old site that has 18k pages and many developers coding and writing functions over the years (without documentation) to discern which functions are being used on which pages and if there are functions that are not being used on the site at all, deprecate them.

Comment: You may want to look into some static code analysis. At least part of this (deprecating unused functions) is a solved problem. Not sure what dev environment you're using but I'm sure that I saw something in Eclipse that does this.

Comment: Thanks Stephan. I am using PHPStorm by Jetbrains. I will look to see if there something similar to this.

Comment: PHPStorm claims code analysis in its feature set. This may work for you. Keep in mind that in order for it to detect function use problems, you *may* need to import WP core into your project. Or you can create a separate analysis project that includes WP, from the root, *and* your plugins/themes in `wp-content`.